# how to can use variable in in_array() if it possible?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code.
Is this Right?

```
<?php
$os = "1,2,3";
$oss = array($os);
$pp  = '2';
if (in_array($pp, $oss)) {
    echo "my code";
}
```

in this case `$os` is a var from my script that is equal to `(1,2,3,4,...)`
i want to show "my code" if `$pp` is on `$oss` arrays.

Comment: Explode sting to make it array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$os = "1,2,3";
//Bro You just need to explode bebore check using in_array()
$oss = explode(',', $os);

$pp  = '2';
if (in_array($pp, $oss)) {
    echo "my code";
} 


// Another example 
$pp  = '4';
if (in_array($pp, $oss)) {
    echo "my code";
} else {
    echo 'Buzzinga! you"re wrong';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have:

```
$os = "1,2,3";
$oss = array($oss);
```

To make `$oss` array, you should use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), e.g.

```
$oss = explode(',', $os); // split a string by another string (comma)

print_r($oss);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$os = "1,2,3";
$pp  = '2';
if (in_array($pp, explode(',',$os))) {
  echo "my code";
}
```